# Using parameter as column name in Redash

Tags: sql, mariadb, dynamic-sql, redash

In Redash, is there a way to use a parameter as a column name in the query.
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN {{ Parameter }} = "Label Column 1" THEN COLUMN_1
    WHEN {{ Parameter }} = "Label Column 2" THEN COLUMN_2
    ELSE COLUMN_3
END
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ...;
```

Comment: That's an attempt of _dynamic SQL_.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below in Sql Server:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL='SELECT CASE
    WHEN '+CAST(@PARAMETER AS varchar(50))+' = ''Label Column 1'' THEN COLUMN_1
    WHEN '+CAST(@PARAMETER AS varchar(50))+' = ''Label Column 2'' THEN COLUMN_2
    ELSE COLUMN_3
END
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ...;'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i use mariadb database. Thanks anyway.